# Register dll in COMPLUS application using powershell

Tags: powershell, com, command, powershell-2.0

I have a COMPLUS apllication of activation type "1".Now i want to register few dlls under this application,that will get list down under components tab of the application.suppose the dll name is test1.dll.
How can i do this.I came to know about ICOMAdminCatalog::InstallComponent,but not getting a syntax to use it.Please help :)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/256403/administer-com-from-powershell

Comment: @david :Thanks for the reply.the link u have given provides us with the already present components inside a complus application.What i need is how can i add a new component inside this application.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$comAdmin = New-Object -comobject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog;
$comAdmin.InstallComponent("MyApplication", "MyLibrary.dll", $null, $null);
```

Note: If you're adding a new application, make sure you `$apps.SaveChanges()` first.